# behavior for < iOS 4.0?

Tags: iphone

OK, I understand that [UIView beginAnimations:context:] is not recommended for iOS 4.0 and above.

If you go with the recommendation and use [UIView animateWithDuration:animations:], will the app be broken if run on iOS < 4.0?

In other words, the docs are not clear on whether the new-and-improved will work below 4.0.

If it doesn't, why wouldn't one just stick with the old approach for now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will not work in iOS version less then 4.0

Comment: It would seem to me that there's very little incentive then to use the new and recommended approach.  How would one handle this?